# Python Dictionaries Homework

Tags: python

I could use some help with my MyProgrammingLab homework assignment that I have. The output is not in the correct order. I need the entered name to become the first in the output list and then have it removed from the rest of the list below.

For example, if I put in the name `Albus Dumbledore` and it is output to the output file then the output file would be

`Albus Dumbledore`

`Harry Potter`

`Hermione Granger`

instead of

`Harry Potter`

`Hermione Granger`

`Albus Dumbledore`

Here is what I have so far:

```
# displays the menu
def menu():
   print('Enter')
   print('1) look up an email address')
   print('2) add a new name and email address')
   print('3) change an email address')
   print('4) delete a name and email address')
   print('5) save address book and exit')


# phonebook dictionary
phoneBook = {}

# open the file
with open('phonebook.in') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()

   for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
       # add to dictionary
       phoneBook[lines[i].rstrip('\n')] = lines[i+1].rstrip('\n')

# display the menu repeatedly
choice = ''
while choice != '5':
   menu()
   choice = input('test [1-5]: ')
 # If I remove the choice = test [1-5] then the code doesn't have any output in the MyProgrammingLab 
# program, so I am not sure how to fix it because I need to remove it eventually.

   if choice == '1':
       name = input('Enter the name: ')
       if name in phoneBook.keys():
           print(phoneBook[name])
       else:
           print('Sorry, no contact exists under that name.')
   elif choice == '2':
       name = input('Enter the name: ')
       email = input('Enter the email: ')
       if name in phoneBook.keys():
           print('Name already exists')
       else:
           phoneBook[name] = email
           print('Added successfully')
   elif choice == '3':
       name = input('Enter the name: ')
       if name in phoneBook.keys():
           email = input('Enter a new email address: ')
           phoneBook[name] = email
           print('Email changed successfully')
       else:
           print('Sorry, no contact exists under that name.')
   elif choice == '4':
       name = input('Enter the name: ')
       if name in phoneBook.keys():
           del phoneBook[name]
           print('Deleted successfully')
       else:
           print('Sorry, no contact exists under that name.')
   elif choice == '5':
       sorted = {k : phoneBook[k] for k in sorted(phoneBook)}
       # open file to write
       f_out = open("phonebook.out", "w")
       for rec in phoneBook.keys():
           f_out.write(rec + '\n')
           f_out.write(phoneBook[rec] + '\n')
       f_out.close()
       print('Address bok has been saved to phonebook.out')
   else:
       print('Invalid Choice')
```

This is the output that I am getting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am2n2.jpg

Comment: you never use that variable `sorted` (also, give it another name, you're shadowing the built-in `sorted` function)

Comment: Personally I'm a bit unclear on the question, are you saying that when you add a new address with 2, you want the name to be top of the list output in 5? Or that you want the list output in 5 to be in alphabetical order? Or something else :S

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is helpful. I think your ultimate goal is to get the input to be at the top of the list. Two way you can achieve this:

1. Using `+` operator:
   Example:

   ```
   to_insert = 56 int_list = [13, 5, 78, 19, 66]

   int_list = [to_insert] + int_list

   print(int_list)
   ```
2. Using `.insert(index, value)` method:
   Example:

   ```
   int_list = [13, 56, 5, 78, 100]

   int_list.insert(0, 24)

   print(int_list)
   ```